# Sort by date ASC in qweb report odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want sort data in my qweb report by date asc.

My example:

```xml
<t t-foreach="doc.line_ids" t-as="o"> 
   <tr>
       <td class="text-right">
           <span t-field="o.date"/>
        </td> 
   </tr>
</t>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved the problem with following code:

```xml
<t t-foreach="doc.line_ids.sorted(key=lambda x: x.date)" t-as="o"> 
   <tr>
       <td class="text-right">
           <span t-field="o.date"/>
        </td> 
   </tr>
</t>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Hello user_odoo,**

**sorted()**
returns a recordset sorted by the provided key function. If no key is provided, use the model's default sort order:

```
#sort records by name
records.sorted(key=lambda r: r.name)
```

**sorted(key=None, reverse=False)**
Return the recordset self ordered by key.

**Parameters**
**key** -- either a function of one argument that returns a comparison key for each record, or None, in which case records are ordered according the default model's order
**reverse** -- if True, return the result in reverse order

Your problem solution is below code try,

```
<tr t-foreach="doc.order_line.sorted(key=lambda record: record.name, reverse=False)" t-as="ol"> 
    <td class="text-right">
        <span t-field="ol.name"/>
    </td>
    ...
</tr>
```

I hope my answer is helpful.
If any query so comments, Please.